# Variable number of cases on switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Is there a way to do a variable number of cases using switch?
For example:

```
int i = 0;
char c;

public void Test(int x, String s){
     while(i < s.length)
     {
         switch(c)
         {
             case 'a':
                break;
             case 'b':
                break;
               ...
         }
       i++;
     }

}
```

How can I do to the number of cases in the example be the same as the variable x? (If x = 10, the number of cases will be 10 then, and so on)

Comment: What are you trying to do because there is a better way to do what you are asking if you give us a more specific topic.

Comment: If you need a variable number of switch cases, then you are approaching your problem the wrong way.

Comment: The question marked as a duplicate does not ask the same question that OP asked. Flagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. `Switch` uses constants for evaluation. So you need to use `if` statements if you need more flexibility.